# Use second time navigation.js in underscores

Tags: theme-development, javascript

I try to add a button dropdown in my theme underscores (without menu, simple div).

I would like to use the script of navigation.js already present to notduplicate :

```
( function() {
    var container, button, menu, links, i, len;

    container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
    if ( ! container ) {
        return;
    }

    container2 = document.getElementById( 'share-menu' );
    if ( ! container ) {
        return;
    }

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            container.className += ' toggled';
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };

    // Get all the link elements within the menu.
    links    = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
        links[i].addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocus() {
        var self = this;

        // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
        while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

            // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
            if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                    self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                } else {
                    self.className += ' focus';
                }
            }

            self = self.parentElement;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Toggles `focus` class to allow submenu access on tablets.
     */
    ( function( container ) {
        var touchStartFn, i,
            parentLink = container.querySelectorAll( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' );

        if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
            touchStartFn = function( e ) {
                var menuItem = this.parentNode, i;

                if ( ! menuItem.classList.contains( 'focus' ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    for ( i = 0; i < menuItem.parentNode.children.length; ++i ) {
                        if ( menuItem === menuItem.parentNode.children[i] ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        menuItem.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove( 'focus' );
                    }
                    menuItem.classList.add( 'focus' );
                } else {
                    menuItem.classList.remove( 'focus' );
                }
            };

            for ( i = 0; i < parentLink.length; ++i ) {
                parentLink[i].addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchStartFn, false );
            }
        }
    }( container ) );
} )();
```

But I do not reach there.

I tried to duplicate the html, but that did not work.

I thus copied out the html and the Javascript by changing names:

Html :

```
<div id="example1">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="example2" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="myicon"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="example2" aria-expanded="false">my content</div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
( function() {
    var container2, button2, menu2;

    container2 = document.getElementById( 'example1' );

    button2 = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];

    menu2 = container.getElementById( 'example2' )[0];

    menu2.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );

    button2.onclick = function() {
        container2.className += ' toggled';
        button2.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        menu2.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
    };

} )();
```

But there either it does not work (no event on button for example).

Would you have a simple solution to this problem which I turned in all directions? ;)